# How should I encrypt my data in a PHP application?

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, production-environment

I was trying to use the Paypal PHP SDK and I noticed a warning that says I should encrypt my API username and password for use in production environments. I do agree on this statement, but I'm wondering how I should go about doing that. I currently have no clue.

Here's what the warning says, just for the record:

> Do not embed plaintext credentials in your application code. Doing so
>   is insecure and against best practices. Your API credentials must be
>   handled securely. Please consider encrypting them for use in any
>   production environment, and ensure that only authorized individuals
>   may view or modify them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: encode != encrypt. What do you mean?

Comment: Oh sorry, did a few typos and mistakes in the OP. Yes, I meant encrypt, and the PHP Paypal SDK. Correcting now.

Comment: @Gabrielle: Are you on a shared server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set an encryption key:

```
$key = 'yourpasswordhere';
$string = ' confidential information here '; // note the spaces
```

Encrypt it on DB entry or from another file and only store the encrypted string in the file itself:

```
$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
var_dump($encrypted); // "ey7zu5zBqJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp+KSNR4/GAv14w="
```

Decrypt it later:

```
$decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
var_dump($decrypted); // " confidential information here "
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can store credentials like this in a file outside of the web root.  This limits risk, but doesn't get rid of it entirely.

If they can see your code (or even worse, edit it), then they can get your credentials anyway.  Encrypting it means you need your encryption key somewhere that would be just as visible as the username/password itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what if I don't have access beyond the root of the web folder? It seems that it doesn't make much difference in terms of security than storing the credentials as plain text.

Comment: Block access to it with .htaccess