# How create serial key like encrypted string

Tags: php

below snippet which encrypt the string but encrypted string looks like random alphanumeric. but i want encrypted string like

> 5214-6548-4584-4568-abcd  or ABCD-TEST-1F2D-FSDF

My snippet

```
$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
var_dump($encrypted); // "ey7zu5zBqJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp+KSNR4/GAv14w="
```

the below snippet i took from [source encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833448/how-should-i-encrypt-my-data-in-a-php-application)

How to create serial number using client MAC+HOST+os

Comment: I think you first want to read about the differences between a key and encryption.

Comment: "Encryption" implies "decryption". Do you really actually want an *encryption* system or just a system to generate random strings or a *hash*?

Comment: to decrypt encrypted string we have to pass key, this is called key.  encryption is nothing but to encrypt readable database into unreadable data is called encryption @arkascha.

Comment: i want to generate serial key using customer machine (MAC+HOST+OS)

Comment: So you're looking for a **hash**?!

Comment: yes, somthing like that

Comment: In that case, unless you need it to be super-secure, a single round of sha1_sum() should do thetrick and leave you some nice hex data.